# jquery : javascript dialog box appears only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

This div [#divSaveAndDistribute] appears only once. how can i make it appear anytime it is triggered? Thanks

```
  pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
pic1.src = "images/loader.gif";

$(document).ready(function(){


$("#save").live('click',function() {

//alert("you just clicked me");


var table="products_tb";         

$("#status").html('<img src="images/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking empty fields...');
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

var dataString = 'table='+table;
    //alert(dataString);

    //$("#alert").fadeIn(200).html('<img src="images/load/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle">');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkEmpty.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,

        success: function(html)
        {
```

//                $("#alert").fadeOut(200);

```
    // $(".confirm").easyconfirm();
        $("#status").html(html);
```

//                $("#pled").val("");

```
        }
    //clear_form_elements("form#CommentForm");

       });

    });

$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height:200,
                    width:400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "check": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {                        
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                //alert("you just offed me");
                $('#divSaveAndDistribute').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `... it appear anytime it is triggered ...`? The same "it", or two different "it"?

Comment: Where is the rest of the code ? even better create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be help full:
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog("open");
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog("close");

On the bottom of this site: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ you have list of methods, events and options